# Bug in cell item deletion into custom adapter

Tags: android

I have an listview item with a delete button: when this button is pressed the row is deleted.
My adapter extends CursorAdapter as data is stored into a sqllite db.

Deletion code is into the custom adapter:

```
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor c) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();

    if(holder == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.id = c.getInt(ID);
        holder.delB = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.delB);

        final int id = holder.id;


        holder.delB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                context.getContentResolver().delete(SeriesContentProvider.SERIES_CONTENT_URI,
                        DBHelper.COLUMN_ID+"=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

            }
        });


        view.setTag(holder);
 }
```

This is what happens, say you have this list:

item1
item2
item3

I decide to delete item2, everything works fine:

item1
item3

Now I delete item3, this is what I get:

item3

item1 got deleted instead! Why?

Edit:
ok it just happens if first I add an new item. Anyway, if I add the item, close the app, and start it again it works fine. I checked with some System.out and it seems that, when I add the new item, the id attribute of holder classes is messed up...

Comment: Is it possible that the bug is in the ContentProvider? Have you tried deleting a hardcoded value as a test?

Comment: No, content provider is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved...problem was that I called the getID method into the holder, so cells update was not noticed:

```
if(holder == null){
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.delB = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.delB);
    ...
}
   holder.id = c.getInt(ID); //this solved
```